# Database query to fill selection field

Tags: php, database, selection

Some years ago I have added a small script to my website getting data from the database to fill options of a selection field.

Recently, I had to change the database table but although I adapted the fieldnames and table name the script is not working anymore but I cannot figure out, why.

Below, there is the script that I use for fetching the data:

```php
// Prepare the empty array
$items = array();
// Prepare the database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Keep this if you'd like a "Please select" option, otherwise comment or remove it
$items[] = "|Please select[c]";
 
// Run the SQL query and store it in $results
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM  icoh1_eb_events WHERE event_date >= NOW() AND published > 0 ORDER BY event_date");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
 
// Now, we need to convert the results into a readable RSForm! Pro format.
// The Items field will accept values in this format:
// value-to-be-stored|value-to-be-shown
// Eg. m|M-sized T-shirt
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $value = $result->title;
  $label = $result->title;
  $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
}
 
// Multiple values are separated by new lines, so we need to do this now
$items = implode("\n", $items);
 
// Now we need to return the value to the field
return $items;
```

Of course there are much more fields in this table but these are the fields in question:
[image: 1]

My question is: Why does my script not work as intended.

Comment: Don't you have any errors? If it is not working you may want to debug the result set and see if it has any entries and you may want to enable error reporting (see php.net) for the debugging.

Comment: Have you updated PHP version? if yes then maybe you have to change your DB class as the MySQL query function is no longer supported in new version Instead you have to use mysqli query function